# Reading collection from Firestore with Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to get the document in my collection "Cities" in Firestore using cloud function, the collection is the same as the tutorial.

```
'use strict';

const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault()
});

var db = admin.firestore();
var test ;
exports.helloWorld = (req, res) => {
var citiesRef = db.collection('cities/');
var allCities = citiesRef.get()
    .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            //console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
            test = doc.data();
            res.status(200).send("Data");
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error getting documents', err);
    });
  let message = req.query.message || req.body.message || 'Hello World!';
  res.status(200).send(test);
};
```

The problem is that snapshot is empty so it doesn't return my response message. What is the correct way of reading all the data in the collection for cloud function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must send the response only when data fetch from the database.

```
exports.helloWorld = (req, res) => {
    var citiesRef = db.collection('cities');
    var allCities = citiesRef.get()
        .then(snapshot => {

            if (snapshot.empty) {
                return res.status(404).send("No data to found");
            } 

            // create data array
            const snapshotData = [];

            snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                test = doc.data();

                // put data into the array
                snapshotData.push(test);
            });

            // send response with all data
            res.status(200).send(snapshotData);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('Error getting documents', err);
            res.status(500).send(err);
        });
    };
```

Comment: Test Function result in "No data to found". Why is it the case? I do have the collection and data inside.

Comment: Screenshot of my DB https://prnt.sc/vl7a89 . I suspect that there is a problem with my function. It would be awesome to see the working code for querying data in a collection.

Comment: Download service account file and initializeApp with it. [Follow this document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that none of your calls to `res.send()` are in a good place.  It must only be called once for the entire function.  You have one inside a loop (which would be bad if the query returned multiple documents), and another one sending a response *before* anything happens with the query, which is asynchronous.  Calling then does not pause the program - it just returns immediately with a new promise.  (You will definitely have to understand how JavaScript promises work in order to make effective use of Cloud Functions, otherwise nothing will work as you expect.)

Try something more like this, where you send only one response after the query is complete, and also send and error response in that case.

```
exports.helloWorld = (req, res) => {
  var citiesRef = db.collection('cities/');
  var allCities = citiesRef.get()
    .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            //console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
            test = doc.data();
        });
        res.status(200).send(test);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error getting documents', err);
        res.status(500).send("Some error");
    });
});
```